# How to Reduce PDF size in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, pdf, size, reduce

In my app, I just want to print Bitmaps on PDF document and save it.
I can did that without any error.

But the thing is file size is too large like 20/30 MB.

Therefore I just try with Grayscale Bitmaps. After that file size is reduce somewhat (10 MB), but still it's very large.

**My problem is how I can reduce the PDF File size in Android Studio.**

```java
    if (img_SetImage) {
    
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    
        opt.inScaled = false;
    
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_Uri.getPath(), opt);
        int[] xyImg = xy(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 298, 175);
    
        PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page myPage = myPDFDoc.startPage(myPageInfo);
    
        Canvas myCanvas = myPage.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    
        float wScale, hScale, scaleFactor;
        wScale = xyImg[0] / (float) bmp.getWidth();
        hScale = xyImg[1] / (float) bmp.getHeight();
    
            if (wScale >= hScale) {
                scaleFactor = hScale;
            } else {
                scaleFactor = wScale;
            }
    
        myCanvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, xyImg[2]/scaleFactor, xyImg[3]/scaleFactor, paint);
        myPDFDoc.finishPage(myPage);
        bmp.recycle();
    }
    
    
    private int[] xy(float width, float height, float left, float top) {
        int finalWidth, finalHeight, finalLeft, finalTop;
        float wScale, hScale, scaleFactor;
        wScale = (436 / width);
        hScale = (270 / height);
    
        if (wScale >= hScale) {
            scaleFactor = hScale;
        } else {
            scaleFactor = wScale;
        }
    
        finalWidth = (int) (width * scaleFactor);
        finalHeight = (int) (height * scaleFactor);
        finalLeft = (int) (left - (finalWidth / 2));
        finalTop = (int) (top - (finalHeight / 2));
    
        int[] returnValues = {finalWidth, finalHeight, finalLeft, finalTop};
    
        return returnValues;
    }
```

Comment: @KJ My app output file size is 34MB, while it gives 409KB from MS Word (save as PDF). File size different is 34MB, but both gave same quality for naked eyes. I just want to save the file with KB capacity like it can do by MS Word.

Comment: @KJ Brother, can you give me the code sample to do that

Comment: Please post a link to a sample PDF file so we can see why it is so large. Then we can provide suggestions on how to reduce its size.

Comment: Thanks everyone who tried to help me. I appreciate that. The problem was I used "android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument" to generate a PDF document. Its ok for text file, but when it has images it doesn't make food result. So I just rewrite the program with "iText7" and it gives me the expected result.